# Chrome 66 - Flash won't display in iframe until zoom is toggled

Tags: google-chrome, flash, swfobject

In the latest version of Chrome, 66, I am having an issue getting flash in an embedded iframe to work as it always has.  I am using swfobject to add the flash content.

The problem is the flash will not display until you toggle chromes internal zoom feature.  You can zoom to 110%, zoom back out, and it will render.

Things to know and what I've tried:

- The content is larger than 400x300 (chrome blocks this)
- the content is not hidden (chrome blocks this)
- I have tried hardcoding pixel flashParams for width and height, whereas we used to use only pixel height and let width be 100%
- I have tried specifying the flashParam  `play: false` just in case as chrome 66 blocks autoplay (previously not specified at all)
- Once it's resolved by toggling the zoom, the 'fix' persists even if I close the tab and reopen.

How can I get this to render without this not-at-all-obvious workaround?

I realize swfobject is no longer maintained.  We have migrated most everything off flash but I will need to maintain this probably until the end of the year at least.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. Finally, I found a solution: instead of `swfobject`, just use a single `<embed>` tag.

Comment: the thing about swfobject is it does a lot of checking and handling. Checking versions, making sure the page is _really_ rendered, making sure flash version works, etc.   I spent a full day in chrome debug tools stepping through everything with this and couldn't get to a spot that obviously did something weird, and obviously no error thrown.  I'd hate to back out and just make an <embed>, but Chrome is leaving few choices.  This is still broken (but hardly used) for us.